# PHP strange echo behavior

Tags: php, css, echo

I have noticed a very strange PHP behavior, where echo function seems to affect the styling of some elements on the page.

when I use:

```
echo "<ul>";
echo "<li><a class='item'><span class='item-icon'></span>Item-1</a></li>";
echo "<li><a class='item'><span class='item-icon'></span>Item-2</a></li>";
echo "</ul>";
```

I get "item-icon" slightly out of position.

But when I use this I get correct icon positions:

```
echo "<ul>";
?>
<li><a class="item"><span class="item-icon"></span>Item-1</a></li>
<li><a class="item"><span class="item-icon"></span>Item-2</a></li>
<?php
echo "</ul>";
```

I can still fix the css and use the first syntax, but I am very curious to know what is causing this porblem!!

**Answer:**
Thanks to Brad Kent, adding line break to the echo fixed the problem!!

```
echo "<ul>";
echo "<li><a class='item'><span class='item-icon'></span>Item-1</a></li>\r\n";
echo "<li><a class='item'><span class='item-icon'></span>Item-2</a></li>\r\n";
echo "</ul>";
```

Comment: Second (giving correct) has line breaks, first doesn't

Comment: Can you show the relevant css so we can reproduce it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

depending on what CSS is being applied...

version A contains no line breaks between the `<li>`s
version B does contain line breaks betwen the `<li>`s

```
<li>blah</li><li>blah</li>
```

vs

```
<li>blah</li>
<li>blah</li>
```

it can make a difference

Comment: You are right I have added "\r\n" at the end of each echo and it worked !!! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Missing `=` in this line?

```
                  v
echo "<li><a class'item'><span class='item-icon'></span>Item-1</a></li>";
```

Single quotes are okay.